# Rhino Mock OfType<>

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Im trying to test this statement

```
IStudentAssessmentUnitStatus res = student.UnitStatusList.OfType<IStudentAssessmentUnitStatus>().
                                                                                FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == unit.ID);
```

Inside the list there could be multiple types hence the OfType. However when testing it says "Object reference not set to an instance"

```
     var _mockStudentFormUnit = _mockery.DynamicMock<IStudentAssessmentUnitStatus>();
     var _mockStudentAssessmentUnit = _mockery.DynamicMock<IStudentFormUnitStatus>();

     var studentunitList = new List<IStudentUnitStatus>() { _mockStudentFormUnit, _mockStudentAssessmentUnit };

     var mockEnum2 = _mockery.DynamicMock<IEnumerable<IStudentUnitStatus>>();

     Expect.Call(_mockStudent2.UnitStatusList).Return(mockEnum2).Repeat.Any();
     Expect.Call(mockEnum2.GetEnumerator()).Return(null).WhenCalled(s => s.ReturnValue = studentunitList.GetEnumerator()).Repeat.Any();
```

Can any Rhino experts see what I have done wrong . The above works fine for enumerations and OfType technically should just do a foreach and perform an "is" operation

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of student.UnitStatusList? , can you please show us?

Comment: The line you want to test contains two calls: A call to the extension method "OfType" and then a call to the extension method "FirstOrDefault".  Both of these are .NET Framework calls so you're really just testing the .NET Framework (probably not what you want to test).  It's not clear what "student" is, but if the UnitStatusList is a virtual property, you should have no problems stubbing that out with Rhino Mocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the last line with:

```
Expect.Call(mockEnum2.GetEnumerator()).Do(new Func<IEnumerator<IStudentUnitStatus>>(s => studentunitList.GetEnumerator())).Repeat.Any();
```

(You may have to change `IEnumerator<IStudentUnitStatus>` to `IEnumerator` to get this to work.)